# Getting FileNotFoundException IOException errors while running Spring in IntelliJ with the help of Maven

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, filenotfoundexception, ioexception

I am trying to run *HelloWrld* in **Spring Framework**. To find my **bean** definition I am accessing a file called ***spring.xml***. But I get the error mentioned in the title.

Here is the **initial** project structure:

[image]

And I then pasted the same file ***spring.xml*** in all directories and sub-directories hoping that one would be picked (following is a screenshot of that), but it did not work and I keep getting the same error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a 'resources' folder under src/main.
And copy the spring.xml file under the resource folder
Do not forget to do: Mark Directory as : Resources Root (with right click)

Comment: Do not forget to do: Mark Directory as : Resources Root (with right click)

Comment: I have followed your instructions, but unfortunately, it still does not work.

Comment: did you do a maven clean before launching the app ?

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is incorrect.

Add your `spring.xml` file in a folder `src/main/resources` - note the "s".

You can see where I have a similar configuration, my `api.yaml` file sits there

[image: Example resources folder]